# How to prevent @change event when changing v-model value

Tags: vuejs2

I'm building an auto-complete menu in Vue.js backed by Firebase (using vue-fire).  The aim is to start typing a user's display name and having match records show up in the list of divs below.

The template looks like this:

```
<b-form-input id="toUser"
    type="text"
    v-model="selectedTo"
    @change="searcher">
</b-form-input>

<div v-on:click="selectToUser(user)" class="userSearchDropDownResult" v-for="user in searchResult" v-if="showSearcherDropdown">{{ user.name }}</div>
```

Upon clicking a potential match the intention is to set the value of the  field and clear away the list of matches.

Here is the code portion of the component:

```
computed: {
  /* method borrowed from Reddit user imGnarly: https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/63w65c/client_side_autocomplete_search_with_vuejs/ */
  searcher() {
    let self = this;
    let holder = [];
    let rx = new RegExp(this.selectedTo, 'i');
    this.users.forEach(function (val, key) {
      if (rx.test(val.name) || rx.test(val.email)) {
        let obj = {}
        obj = val;
        holder.push(obj);
      } else {
        self.searchResult = 'No matches found';
      }
    })
    this.searchResult = holder;
    return this.selectedTo;
  },

  showSearcherDropdown() {
    if(this.searchResult == null) return false;
    if(this.selectedTo === '') return false;
    return true;
  }
},

methods: {
  selectToUser: function( user ) {
    this.newMessage.to = user['.key'];
    this.selectedTo = user.name;
    this.searchResult = null;
  }
}
```

Typeahead works well, on each change to the input field the searcher() function is called and populates the searchResult with the correct values.   The v-for works and a list of divs is shown.

Upon clicking a div, I call selectToUser( user ).   This correctly reports details from the user object to the console.

However, on first click I get an exception in the console and the divs don't clear away (I expect them to disappear because I'm setting searchResults to null).

```
[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "change": "TypeError: fns.apply is not a function"

found in

---> <BFormInput>
       <BFormGroup>
         <BTab>

TypeError: fns.apply is not a function
    at VueComponent.invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:2004)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$emit (vue.esm.js?efeb:2515)
    at VueComponent.onChange (form-input.js?1465:138)
    at boundFn (vue.esm.js?efeb:190)
    at invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:2004)
    at HTMLInputElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (vue.esm.js?efeb:1802)
```

If I click the div a *second* time then there's no error, the input value is set and the divs disappear.

So I suspect that writing a value to this.selectedTo (which is also the v-model object for the  element is triggering a @change event.   On the second click the value of  doesn't actually change because it's already set, so no call to searcher() and no error.

I've noticed this also happens if the  element loses focus.

**Question**: how to prevent an @change event when changing v-model value via a method?

(other info: according to package.json I'm on vue 2.5.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@acdcjunior, thanks for your answer.

Of course just removing the reference to `searcher()` just means no action is taken upon field value change so the field won’t work at all.

Moving the `searcher()` function into `methods: {}` instead of `computed: {}` means that it will be called on an input event and not a change even (another mystery but not one for today).  A subtle difference that takes away the typeahead feature I’m aiming at.

However, it did make me remember that the result of `computed: {}` functions are cached and will be re-computed when any parameters change.  In this case I realised that the `searcher()` function is dependent upon the `this.selectedTo` variable.   So when the `selectToUser()` function sets `this.selectedTo` it triggers another call to `searcher()`.

Fixed now.  In case anyone has a similar problem in the future, I resolved this by turning to old fashioned semaphore by adding another variable.

```
var userMadeSelection: false
```

Now, searcher() begins with a check for this scenario:

```
  computed: {
      searcher() {
          if(this.userMadeSelection) {
            this.userMadeSelection = false;
            return this.selectedTo;
          }
          …
```

and then in selectToUser():

```
this.userMadeSelection = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

On:

```
<b-form-input id="toUser"
    type="text"
    v-model="selectedTo"
    @change="searcher">
```

The "searcher" should be a method. A method that will be called whenever that `b-component` issues a `change` event.

But looking at your code, it is not a method, but a `computed`:

```
computed: {
  searcher() {
    ...
  },

  showSearcherDropdown() {
    ...
  }
},

methods: {
  selectToUser: function( user ) {
   ...
  }
}
```

So when the `change` event happens, it tries to call something that is not a method (or, in other words, it tries to call a method that doesn't exist). That's why you get the error.

Now, since what you actually want is to update `searcher` whenever `this.selectedTo` changes, to get that, it is actually not needed to have that `@change` handler. This is due to the code of `computed: { searcher() {` already depending on `this.selectedTo`. Whenever  `this.selectedTo` changes, Vue will calculate `searcher` again.

**Solution:** simply remove `@change="searcher"` from `b-form`. Everything else will work.